# Select all child elements of a class. CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to apply styles to all the elements of a class directly without having to write like this:

```
.element-wrapper .coin-box{
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.element-wrapper .platform{
 margin: 10px;
 float: left;
}

.element-wrapper .goomba{
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: `.element-wrapper *`

Comment: thank you, didnt know about it

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/n0qeva8L/).

Comment: if different elements are there `.element-wrapper .coin-box, .element-wrapper .platform , .element-wrapper .goomba{/* styles here */}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use * selector, for example:

```
.element-wrapper *{
      margin: 10px;
      float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Descendent selectors** are very similar to child selectors, except that child selectors only select immediate descendents; descendent selectors select matching elements anywhere in the element hierarchy, not just direct descendents. Let's look at what this means more carefully.

CSS:

```
.element-wrapper >  *
 {
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
 }
```

It will work more consistently :-

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this

```
 .element-wrapper .coin-box, .element-wrapper .platform, .element-wrapper .goomba {
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```